# mnist neural network: Please fix the functions

Tags: neural-network, mnist

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

k = 784
l = 50
m = 100
n = 10

eps = 0.1
Nb = 100

####### mnist data load  ##########################################
import pickle
f = open('mydata.pkl', 'rb')
test_img, test_label, train_img, train_label = pickle.load(f)
train_img = train_img/255
test_img  = test_img/255
f.close()

####################################################################

####### SYSTEM VARIABLES & Initialization  #########################

x = zeros((k,1))

z1 = zeros((l,Nb))
s1 = zeros((l,Nb))
z2 = zeros((m,Nb))
s2 = zeros((m,Nb))
z3 = zeros((n,Nb))
p = zeros((n,Nb))

A1 = random.randn(l,k)
b1 = random.randn(l,1)
A2 = random.randn(m,l)
b2 = random.randn(m,1)
A3 = random.randn(n,m)
b3 = random.randn(n,1)

ndH_db2 = zeros((m,l))
ndH_dA1 = zeros((l,k))
ndH_db1 = zeros((l,1))



###################################################################

###### Function definitions #######################################
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + exp(-x))

def P(z3):
    C = z3.max(0)
    p = exp(z3-C)
    
    return p/ p.sum(0)

def F(x):
    global z1, s1, z2, s2, z3, p
    z1 = A1@x + b1
    s1 = sigmoid(z1)
    z2 = A2@s1 + b2
    s2 = sigmoid(z2)
    z3 = A3@s2 + b3
    p  = P(z3)
    
    return p

def H(B):
    xB = train_img[B].T
    yB = train_label[B]
    p = F(xB)
    
    return (-log(p[yB,range(Nb)]).sum())/Nb

###################################################################

###### For Numerical validation ###################################
def F2(x,A1,b1,A2,b2,A3,b3):
    global z1, s1, z2, s2, z3, p

    z1 = A1@x + b1
    s1 = sigmoid(z1)
    z2 = A2@s1 + b2
    s2 = sigmoid(z2)
    z3 = A3@s2 + b3
    p  = P(z3)
    
    return p

def H2(B,A1,b1,A2,b2,A3,b3):
    xB = train_img[B].T
    yB = train_label[B]
    p = F2(xB,A1,b1,A2,b2,A3,b3)
    
    return (-log(p[yB,range(Nb)]).sum())/Nb

def numerical_DH():
    param_flattened = param.flatten() 
    grad_approx = np.zeros_like(param_flattened)

    for i in range(len(param_flattened)):
        param_plus = param_flattened.copy()
        param_minus = param_flattened.copy()

        param_plus[i] += epsilon  
        param_minus[i] -= epsilon  

        
        val_plus = H2(*args, param_plus.reshape(param.shape))
        val_minus = H2(*args, param_minus.reshape(param.shape))

       
        grad_approx[i] = (val_plus - val_minus) / (2 * epsilon)

    return grad_approx.reshape(param.shape)
####################################################################
    

###### Gradient Computations : Chain Rules #########################

def DH_Dz3():
    global p, train_label
    
    
    one_hot_train_label = eye(n)[train_label].T
    
    
    dH_dz3 = p - one_hot_train_label[:, :p.shape[1]]
    
    dH_dz3 /= Nb
    
    return dH_dz3

def DH_Dalpha3(dH):
    global s2, train_label
    

    dataset_size = len(train_label)


    if dataset_size <= 100:
        random_indices = arange(dataset_size)
    else:
        random_indices = random.choice(dataset_size, min(100, dataset_size), replace=False)
    
    dH = dH_dz3[:, random_indices]


    dS_dz = s2 * (1 - s2)
    dH_ds2 = A3.T @ dH * dS_dz


    dH_dA3 = dH_dz3 @ s2.T

    dH_db3 = np.sum(dH_dz3, axis=1, keepdims=True)

    return dH_ds2, dH_dA3, dH_db3

def DH_DS(dH,s):
    global A3, dH_ds
    

    dS_dz = s * (1 - s)
    dH_ds = A3.T @ dH * dS_dz
    

    return dH_ds

def DH_Dalpha2(dH):
    global s1
    

    dH_dA2 = dH_ds @ s1.T

    dH_db2 = sum(dH_ds, axis=1, keepdims=True)


    return dH_ds, dH_dA2, dH_db2

def DH_Dalpha1(dH):
    global x
    

    dS_dz = s1 * (1 - s1)
    dH_dz1 = A2.T @ dH_ds * dS_dz
    

    dH_dA1 = dH_dz1 @ x.T
 
    dH_db1 = np.sum(dH_dz1, axis=1, keepdims=True)

    return dH_dA1, dH_db1

#####################################################################
    


###### Main Loop ####################################################

for w in range(4):
    B = random.choice(60000,Nb)
    xB = train_img[B].T
    yB = train_label[B]    

    val=H(B)
    print(w,val)
    
    dH_dz3                 = DH_Dz3()
    dH_ds2, dH_dA3, dH_db3 = DH_Dalpha3(dH_dz3)
    dH_dz2                 = DH_DS(dH_ds2,s2)
    dH_ds1, dH_dA2, dH_db2 = DH_Dalpha2(dH_dz2)
    dH_dz1                 = DH_DS(dH_ds1,s1)
    dH_dA1, dH_db1         = DH_Dalpha1(dH_dz1)
    
    A3 = A3 - eps*dH_dA3
    b3 = b3 - eps*dH_db3
    A2 = A2 - eps*dH_dA2
    b2 = b2 - eps*dH_db2
    A1 = A1 - eps*dH_dA1
    b1 = b1 - eps*dH_db1

#####################################################################


####### test #########################################################
def testimage(k):
    x = test_img[k].reshape(784,1)
    img = x.reshape(28,28)
    
    X,Y = meshgrid(arange(0,28,1),arange(27,-1,-1),indexing='xy')
    pl.pcolormesh(X,Y,img)
    p = F(x)
    i = p.argmax()
    pl.title(f'true: {test_label[k]}' + f'   system: {i}')
#######################################################################
```

I have to make a number-matching artificial neural network code, but errors keep popping up. How can I fix this..
I think there's a problem with these functions:
DH_Dz3(),DH_Dalpha3(dH),DH_DS(dH,s),DH_Dalpha2(dH),DH_Dalpha1(dH)

--> 147     dH = dH_dz3[:, random_indices]
148

IndexError: index 54491 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 100